# Change this JS for more Divs

Tags: javascript

I want to change my JavaScript:

```js
function SwapDivsWithClick(div1,div2,div3)
{
   d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
   d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
   d3 = document.getElementById(div3);
   if( d2.style.display & d3.style.display == "none" )
   {
      d1.style.display = "none";
      d2.style.display = "block";
      d3.style.display = "none";
   }
   else
   {
      d1.style.display = "block";
      d2.style.display = "none";
      d3.style.display = "none";
   }
   else
   {
      d1.style.display = "none";
      d2.style.display = "none";
      d3.style.display = "block";
   }
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">
<a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('swapper-first','swapper-other', 'swapper-3')">(Swap Divs)</a>
</p>


<div id="swapper-first" style="display:block; border:2px dashed red; padding:25px;">
<p style="margin:0; color:red;">
This div displayed when the web page first loaded.
</p>
</div>
<div id="swapper-other" style="display:none; border:2px dotted blue; padding:25px;">
<p style="margin:0; color:blue;">
This div displayed when the link was clicked.
</p>
</div>
<div id="swapper-3" style="display:none; border:2px dotted blue; padding:25px;">
<p style="margin:0; color:blue;">
This div displayed when the link was clicked.
</p>
</div>
```

If I click `(Swap divs)` nothing happens, but if I delete `d3` and `div3` and the `else` it works.

I'm new to JavaScript as you can see. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your first if statements condition should be `d2.style.display == "none" && d3.style.display == "none"`. Secondly you can't have an `else` after an `else`. You need to add a `else if ()` condition before last `else`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't put an `else` on the end of another `else`. If you have:

```
if (condition) {
    // A
} else {
    // B
}
```

then all of the alternatives are covered, there's nothing a third `else` could do.

Instead, you use `else if`:

```
if (condition1) {
    // A
else if (condition2) {
    // B
} else {
    // C
}
```

If `condition1` isn't true, it tests `condition2` and if *that* isn't true, it goes into the final `else`.

So you can fix your code by adding another condition in an `else if`, see comments:

```js
function SwapDivsWithClick(div1,div2,div3)
{
   // Always declare your variables!
   var d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
   var d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
   var d3 = document.getElementById(div3);
   // Check them in order
   if (d1.style.display == "block")
   {
      // Switch from d1 to d2
      d1.style.display = "none";
      d2.style.display = "block";
      d3.style.display = "none";
   }
   else if (d2.style.display === "block")
   {
      // Switch from d2 to d3
      d1.style.display = "none";
      d2.style.display = "none";
      d3.style.display = "block";
   }
   else
   {
      // Switch from d3 to d1
      d1.style.display = "block";
      d2.style.display = "none";
      d3.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">
<a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('swapper-first','swapper-other', 'swapper-3')">(Swap Divs)</a>
</p>


<div id="swapper-first" style="display:block; border:2px dashed red; padding:25px;">
<p style="margin:0; color:red;">
This div displayed when the web page first loaded.
</p>
</div>
<div id="swapper-other" style="display:none; border:2px dotted blue; padding:25px;">
<p style="margin:0; color:blue;">
This div displayed when the link was clicked.
</p>
</div>
<div id="swapper-3" style="display:none; border:2px dotted blue; padding:25px;">
<p style="margin:0; color:blue;">
The third div
</p>
</div>
```

---

**But**: I wouldn't do it that way. Instead, I'd put all of those divs in a container, and then use a class to show one of them:

```js
function SwapDivsWithClick(containerId)
{
    // Get the swappable divs within the container
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll("#" + containerId + " > .swappable");
    // Loop through until we find the one that's showing
    for (var n = 0; n < divs.length; ++n) {
        var div = divs[n];
        if (div.classList.contains("showing")) {
            // Find the "next" one, looping back to the beginning if we're
            // at the end. That `(index + 1) % length` trick is a useful one
            // to remember: We'll go 0 -> 1 -> 2 -> 0 -> 1...
            var nextDiv = divs[(n + 1) % divs.length];
            // Hide the one that's currently showing, show the next
            div.classList.remove("showing");
            nextDiv.classList.add("showing");
            // Break the loop, since we found it
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.swappable {
  display: none;
}
.showing {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">
<a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('swap-container')">(Swap Divs)</a>
</p>

<div id="swap-container">
<div class="swappable showing" style="border:2px dashed red; padding:25px;">
<p style="margin:0; color:red;">
This div displayed when the web page first loaded.
</p>
</div>
<div class="swappable" style="border:2px dotted blue; padding:25px;">
<p style="margin:0; color:blue;">
This div displayed when the link was clicked.
</p>
</div>
<div class="swappable" style="border:2px dotted blue; padding:25px;">
<p style="margin:0; color:blue;">
The third div
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

---

Side note: You don't need it here, but for a *logical* OR operation, you use `&&`, not `&`.

Answer (score 1):

When you add a third "possibility", you have to tell the program what the condition for this possibility is. You used two `else` without an `else if`.

I changed this for you and you can see, that I check for two conditions:

1. Is the display style for d2 and d3 none?
2. Is the display style for d1 and d3 none?

Also, if you want to simultaneously check for two conditions

`if(d2.style.display & d3.style.display == "none")`

you will have to do this in two steps:

`if( d2.style.display == "none" && d3.style.display == "none" )`

And the last thing: logical operators in javaScript use `&&` for `and` and `||` for `or`.

I added the snippet for you to try out. Let me know if this helps you!

```js
function SwapDivsWithClick(div1,div2,div3)
{
   d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
   d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
   d3 = document.getElementById(div3);
   if( d2.style.display == "none" && d3.style.display == "none" )
   {
      d1.style.display = "none";
      d2.style.display = "block";
      d3.style.display = "none";
   } else if ( d1.style.display == "none" && d3.style.display == "none") {
      d1.style.display = "none";
      d2.style.display = "none";
      d3.style.display = "block";
   } else {
      d1.style.display = "block";
      d2.style.display = "none";
      d3.style.display = "none";
   }
}
```

```html
<p style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic;">
<button onclick="SwapDivsWithClick('swapper-first','swapper-other', 'swapper-3')">(Swap Divs)</button>
</p>


<div id="swapper-first" style="display:block; border:2px dashed red; padding:25px;">
<p style="margin:0; color:red;">
This div displayed when the web page first loaded.
</p>
</div>
<div id="swapper-other" style="display:none; border:2px dotted blue; padding:25px;">
<p style="margin:0; color:blue;">
This div displayed when the link was clicked once.
</p>
</div>
<div id="swapper-3" style="display:none; border:2px dotted blue; padding:25px;">
<p style="margin:0; color:blue;">
This div displayed when the link was clicked twice.
</p>
</div>
```

EDIT: Oh! I guess I am a little late. It took so long to format this answer.